# what to do with obsolete comments

Tags: support, comments

Suppose I place an answer comment (e.g. elaborate your answer, don't provide only a link bladibla) and the person adjusts the answer and it's worth a +1. Meanwhile, my comment has been upvoted as well, but is now, obviously, obsolete. Do I remove my comment?

Comment: Simple answer: If your comment has been rendered unuseful, delete it. The vote count doesn't matter. Find the full details [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237978/a-guide-to-moderating-comments/237979#237979).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍

Answer (score 3):

Remove it if there's no redeeming value. Some comments can present information even if they address for edit requests which had been commenced, so this is more case-by-case.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, indeed. What's more, if you find such comments posted by others, flag them as obsolete. Comments are supposed to be transient and mods can and will delete them without warning.

Such flags help keep the site free of clutter and give mods a warm fuzzy sense of being useful :)